# Is there a way to change my race in Skyrim: Special Edition on the Xbox?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I first bought Skyrim: Special Edition for my Xbox One and started up a new game, I chose the Argonian race. It was nice at first, but certain gameplay and visual elements of the Argonian race started to annoy me after a while, like the big, ugly tail, facial features, etc.

Is there a way to change my characters race, in game, without starting over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the Cheat Room mod found here https://mods.bethesda.net/#en/workshop/skyrim/mod-detail/3010376

It can allow you to access the ShowRaceMenu command which should let you change your race.

Comment: Is this available on Xbox One? because that's what the op asks

Comment: @Wouter It specifies on the mod page that it is for Xbox One.

Comment: Didn't show up for me last time, now it does so nvm

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no way to change your character's race mid game, without starting over.

There are methods of changing your race as well as various other features of your character, but they're only available for the PC version of Skyrim.

I assume you play in 3rd person mode, as you find the tail to be quite annoying. Maybe you could read up about the Argonian race on the internet, to develop you interest in the race as a whole (I personally enjoy playing as an Argonian.) I recommend reading about the lore of the Shadowscales.

Base link for lore on Shadowscales: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Shadowscales

Answer (score -2):

I know that this is very very very late but for newer people looking you can just enter you console and type the command **showracemenu** you don't need any mods but you do need to be on PC

Comment: This answer is not appropriate for the question: The question is in regards to Xbox One solutions, and your answer only applies to PC